# Overriding Content of SDL Tridion Component using Event Handlers

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

How can a field value of a Component be overridden using Event Handler?  When I have the code snippet below, there is no error while saving the Component. But content changes done by the Event hanlder is not reflected back in the Component. I expect the single value field "size" to have "blabla..." as the value.

```cs
// Call to Subscribe the events
EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, SaveEventArgs>(ComponentSaveInitiatedHandler,
                                                EventPhases.Initiated); 

private void ComponentSaveInitiatedHandler(Component component, 
                                          SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phases)
{
    if (component.Schema.Title == "XYZ")
    {
        ItemFields Fields = new ItemFields(component.Content, component.Schema);
        SingleLineTextField textField = (SingleLineTextField)Fields["size"];
        textField.Value = "blabla...";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to update the Content property with the XML string, as follows:

```
ItemFields Fields = new ItemFields(component.Content, component.Schema);
SingleLineTextField textField = (SingleLineTextField)Fields["size"];
textField.Value = "blabla...";
component.Content = Fields.ToXml();
```

Comment: the reason for this is because the ItemFields collection is a so called detached collection, so making a change in there does not directly update the component.

Comment: In the legacy APIs you could work with a detached collection and then  use it to set the relevant collection property again on the 'parent' object. This looks like the equivalent approach using the core service,  right?

Comment: If you mean the TOM, I don't think the fields collection was detached then. Something like 'Component.Fields("heading").Value(1) = "Test" : Component.Save (True)' would just work. Ah, golden days..